# 'and' keyword in C++

Tags: c++

I have seen `and`  keyword being used inside `if` statement just like `&&` operator. 
Is there any difference between these (`and` , `&&`) ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
bool a = true;
bool b = true;

if(a==true and b==true) // if(a==true && b == true)
{
    cout << "YES ";
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure somebody didn't just do `#define and &&`?

Comment: P.S. it's always bad form to use `a==true` or `a==false`, use `a` or `!a` instead. The canonical C or C++ would be `if (a && b)`.

Comment: I didn't do that . I have edited my question . Please see the full code

Comment: You can check here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: @MarkRansom `a == true` is indeed bad, but I do not see a problem with the more verbose but explicit `true == a` or `nullptr == ptr`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, the new [and keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and) has been around since at least C++98. It operates identically to the `&&` operator.

Comment: actually this worked for c++98 [too](http://cpp.sh/5xdel) check under options for the standard

Comment: Ah, good to know! I'll update.

Comment: More like it's been a part of the language at least since standardization. Not clear that it was "added" in C++98. And it wasn't "added" later.

Comment: yes you are right @juanchopanza I think i confused user1118321 by  saying it worked for c++98 too I am sorry about that

Comment: OK, I have made the wording more accurate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Still can't use it in Visual Studio

Answer (score 14):

There is no difference in `and` and `&&`. you can also use `not` instead of `!` and `or` instead of `||`.